# Dynamically starting a zoom script with jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, zooming

I don't know how to dynamically start the jQuery *Image Power Zoomer v1.1* script from Dynamicdrive. 
I would need to start the zoom on lightbox-type gallery images, but when I call it with click (live) it needs the cursor to be moved out from the picture and back in to get the script started. My preferred method would be the simple mouseenter method, but it seems to be conflicting with the scripts' own mouseenter-mouseleave actions, so I could make the compromise with the click if it's necessary.

The example page is here: 
http://baksagaspar.com/MH-work/collections/jungle-under-construction-2

and I use this script for triggering:

```
jQuery("img#shTopImg").live('click', function() {
jQuery("img#shTopImg").addpowerzoom( { magnifiersize: [200,200] } );
});
```

Any help please, how could I get the script start dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call init event on page loading:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $('a.shutterset_set_1 img').addpowerzoom( { magnifiersize: [200,200] } );
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "a.shutterset_set_1 img" fires the zoom on the thumbnails, and not on the lightbox-generated images, which don't exist on doc.ready. But your proposal gave the idea to use this to trigger the zoom: 
jQuery(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail a").live('click', function(){
jQuery("img#shTopImg").addpowerzoom( { magnifiersize: [200,200] } );
});

But this triggers the zoom only for the first image clicked, if I browse with previous-next it doesn't change the images to zoom. Also, it stucks when the lightbox is closed-reopened. :-((

Comment: See the docs of library you are using to create img lightboxes, find how to use image loaded event (next, prev must fire the same event) and add zoom init function there

Comment: I use "Shutter Reloaded for NextGEN Gallery" js, which is a plain javascript lightbox. So I should add the zoom init there? Should it be AJAX calls with 'live' or simple 'bind'?

Comment: I mean smth like this: `$('elements').shutterReloaded({onImageLoaded: function () { /* here fire zoom init */ } })`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :-(
Where should I put this trigger, in the shutterbox.js? What does the 'elements' mean?
This is in shutter.js:
`
shutterOnload = function(){shutterReloaded.init('sh');}

if (typeof shutterOnload == 'function') {
 if ('undefined' != typeof jQuery) jQuery(document).ready(function(){shutterOnload();});
 else if( typeof window.onload != 'function' ) window.onload = shutterOnload;
 else {oldonld = window.onload;window.onload = function(){if(oldonld){oldonld();};shutterOnload();}};
}
`
- Sorry if it breaks the lines, I don't know how could I get the regular editor?

Comment: please, give a link to shutter.js file

Comment: http://baksagaspar.com/MH-work/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.js

A big Thanks for your devoted help! :-)

Comment: hi. check this script http://jsfiddle.net/Ezf3V/ . I've added call to zoom a the end of `showImg()` method. But zoom have to be loaded before shutter (you may prepend zoom source to the shutter)

Comment: Hi. Thank you! Now it works!!! :-)) I'm really grateful for your help! 
The only problem I noticed is that it is sometimes a bit lazy to initialise the zoom (you have to mousenter-leave a few times). Could it be solved somehow? Also when the zoom moves out of the screen at the bottom, the scrollbars are shown. I tried to set the overflow to hidden, but it didn't help (or I didn't find the right element)